# Trying coding a 5 card poker

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, poker

```
import random, time
from random import shuffle

from enum import Enum

class CardSuits(Enum):
    Hearts = "Hearts"
    Diamonds = "Diamonds"
    Clubs = "Clubs"
    Spades = "Spades"

class CardValues(Enum):
    Two = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
    Five = 5
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Jack = "J"
    Queen = "Q"
    King = "K"
    Ace = "A"


class Card:

    _symbols = {"Hearts": "♥️", "Diamonds": "♦️", "Clubs": "♣️", "Spades": "♠"}

    def __init__(self, suit: CardSuits, value: CardValues) -> None:
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.value.value}{self._symbols[self.suit.name]}"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.value.value}{self._symbols[self.suit.name]}"


def start():
    play = input("You wanna play? ")
    if play.lower() in ("yes", "sure", "yeah"):
        all_cards = [Card(suits, value) for suits in CardSuits for value in CardValues]
        shuffle(all_cards)
        unique_cards = set()
        while len(unique_cards) < 5:
            unique_cards.add(random.choice(all_cards))
        cards = list(unique_cards)
        print("Your cards are:", ", ".join(str(card) for card in cards))
        time.sleep(4)
        while True:
            change_cards = input("Want to change cards? ")
            if change_cards.lower() == "yes":
                quantity = input("Which cards? ")
                
                first = cards[0]
                second = cards[1]
                third = cards[2]
                fourth = cards[3]
                fifth = cards[4]
                first, second, third, fourth, fifth = ("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth")
                def print_new_cards():
                    print("Your new cards are:", ", ".join(str(card) for card in cards))
                
                if quantity.lower() == "none":
                    break

                elif quantity.lower() == first:
                    cards[0] = random.choice(all_cards)
                    print_new_cards()
                    break
                elif quantity.lower() == second:
                    cards[1] = random.choice(all_cards)
                    print_new_cards()
                    break
                elif quantity.lower() == third:
                    cards[2] = random.choice(all_cards)
                    print_new_cards()
                    break
                elif quantity.lower() == fourth:
                    cards[3] = random.choice(all_cards)
                    print_new_cards()
                    break
                elif quantity.lower() == fifth:
                    cards[4] = random.choice(all_cards)
                    print_new_cards()
                    break
                
                elif quantity.lower() == "all":
                    all_cards = [Card(suits, value) for suits in CardSuits for value in CardValues]
                    unique_cards = set()
                    while len(unique_cards) < 5:
                        unique_cards.add(random.choice(all_cards))
                    cards = list(unique_cards)
                    print("Your new cards are:", ", ".join(str(card) for card in cards))
                    break                
                else:
                    print("Invalid cards selected")
            elif change_cards.lower() == "no":    
                break     

        #CHECKING PHASE
            


        #SCORE DASHBOARD?
        
        
        while True:        
            continue_playing = input("You want to keep playing?")
            if continue_playing.lower() == "yes":
                wanna_shuffle = input("Wanna shuffle the deck?")
                if wanna_shuffle.lower() == "yes":
                    shuffle(all_cards)
                    print("Deck shuffled")
                    break
                elif continue_playing.lower() == "no":
                    break
                else:
                    continue
            elif continue_playing.lower() == "no":
                exit()    
        start()   
        
        
    else:
        exit()
    

start()
```

the question is: how can i write a few simple lines of code to change cards by the index without writing every change possibility as I was doing?

My inital idea was to change them by writing in the terminal which cards i would change.

ex. hand: 5♦️, A♦️, K♠, J♣️, 2♦️

n the terminal:

> Want to change cards?

yes

> Which cards?

K spades, J clubs

> Your new cards are: 5♦️, A♦️, 6♥️, 7♥️, 2♦️

But i realized that for me is a little too difficult, so I changed my mind and decided to change cards by writing the index of them.

ex. hand: 5♦️, A♦️, K♠, J♣️, 2♦️

> Which cards?

3, 4   or  3rd, 4rth   or   third, fourth

> Your new cards are: 5♦️, A♦️, 9♠, Q♣️, 2♦️

Comment: PS remove the function definition from the `while` loop (or ask yourself if you really need it)

Comment: Are you asking for better **code**, or a better **user interface**?

Comment: The "CardValues" constants are a bit silly.  You're never going to refer to `Jack` by name in the code, and those can't be sorted.  Just use integers from 0 to 12 and have an array that maps those numbers to human-readable strings.  Imagine how difficult it would be to detect a straight with those constants.

Answer (score 2):

First (and somewhat unrelated): As you shuffle the cards, why don't you just deal the first five (and remove them from the deck), rather than giving random cards and ensuring they are unique:

```
deck = all_cards
shuffle(deck)
hand = deck[:5]
deck = deck[5:]
```

You should follow the same for changing cards, e.g:

```
while True:
    ans = input("Which cards you want to change (1-5, separated by comma): ")
    try:
        cardstochange = [int(i) for i in ans.split(",")]   # turn answer into list of integers (might raise an error)
        for cardidx in cardstochange:
            if cardidx < 1 or cardidx > 5:
                raise ValueError            # Raise an error 'cos the user can't count to 5
            hand[cardidx-1] = deck[0]       # -1 because the index start at 0
            deck = deck[1:]
        break;
    except ValueError: # Catch any bs input here
        print("I didn't get you. Say again!")
```

Comment: Good answer. One suggestion: instead of `except Exception`, catch the _specific_ exception you expect the code to raise. `int()` also raises a `ValueError` for non-integer arguments and there seem to be no other types of exceptions that this code can raise, so you should be fine just catching ValueErrors instead of all exceptions. The danger with catching all exceptions is that you end up hiding actual bugs in the code because you've caught and handled the exception that was supposed to show you the bug without actually knowing what the exception is.

Comment: Another couple of suggestions: 1. Instead of looping over the split string once to convert everything to an integer, and again to change the cards, just loop `for c in ans.split(",")` and then do `cardidx = int(c)` inside the loop. 2. Slicing the list is an O(n) operation where `n` is the number of elements in the slice. On the other hand, popping the last element of a list is O(1), so it's more efficient to do `hand[cardidx-1] = deck.pop()`, which pops the last card from the deck and assigns it to the hand.

Comment: @pho  after/tomorrow i'll read your suggestion comments

Comment: @treuss  I've done the unique cards for set( ), because if didn't, there was a possibility that the terminal printed the same card 2 times (thing that already happened), but now I'll try your changing cards solution. EDIT: I'm trying to understand the 2 lines below raise ValueError, but I only got what you said in the note next to them. And also, to finish that code I have to add a remove and an insert method to change cards, am I right?

Comment: @pho While most of your suggestions are valid, moving the conversion to int inside the loop is actually a bad idea, as a user input of `1,2,a` will result in two cards being swapped before the exception is thrown. Regarding the optimization suggestions, you are of course correct, but I chose clarity over unnecessary micro-optimizations (as the user input will take a magnitude longer than the slicing of the lists) here.